# How to get average of groups by making two groups per day (daytime/nighttime)?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table named thermo storing two different temperatures per 30 minutes

(dt=time | Ti=internal temperature | To=external temperature)

I would like to get alternately the daytime and nighttime average.
This could be by grouping hours **06:00-17:59** and **18:00-05:59**

The best I could do is to have grouped 00:00-11:59 and 12:00-23:59 by the following code:

```
SELECT CAST(strftime('%m%d', dt) AS TIME) || CAST(strftime('%H', dt)/12 AS TIME) AS time,
  round(avg(Ti), 1) AS Ti,
  round(avg(To), 1) AS To,
  FROM thermo WHERE dt > datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime', '-10 days')
  GROUP BY time ORDER BY time;
```

Is there a way to have shifted the time groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` to determine the period of interest:

```
SELECT CAST(strftime('%m%d', dt) AS TIME) as dt,
       (CASE WHEN strftime('%H', dt) BETWEEN 6 AND 17 THEN 'daytime'
             ELSE 'nightime'
         END) as period,
       round(avg(Ti), 1) as Ti,
       round(avg(To), 1) as To
FROM thermo
WHERE dt > datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime', '-10 days')
GROUP BY dt, period
ORDER BY time;
```

Comment: On a second thought, this is not totally correct because on this way the nightime includes the same day's morning (0-6) and afternoon (17-24) temperatures while each morning should be in the group of the previous day's afternoon... An improvement could by by appending at strftime: , "-6 hours"

Comment: @volk . . . Yes, subtracting 6 hours would treat the hours from 0-6 as the previous day, if that is what you really want.